# How to display particular records first in a for reach loop in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have requirement to display particular string records first , for example here i want to display all **Rehman** records first then all others in no particular order.

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Roja</title>
    <artist>Rehman</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Eros</title>
    <artist>Zack</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>BMG</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Rockstar</title>
    <artist>Rehman</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1998</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
    <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS</company>
    <price>8.10</price>
    <year>1973</year>
  </cd>

</catalog>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <xsl:sort select="artist" order ="descending"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result

My CD Collection

**Title Artist**

```
Empire Burlesque    Bob Dylan
Hide your heart Bonnie Tyler
Sylvias Mother  Dr.Hook
Still got the blues Gary Moore
Roja    Rehman
Rockstar    Rehman
Eros    Zack
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Artist</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[artist='Rehman']">
                        <xsl:sort select="artist" order ="descending"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[artist!='Rehman']">
                       <!-- You can use this for sorting of rest -->
                       <!-- <xsl:sort select="artist" order ="descending"/> -->
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Here at SO, we generally like some explanatory commentary to accompany our code, as, after all, it's usually the commentary that actually answers the question.  The accompanying -- very welcome -- code *clarifies*.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to already have most of the pieces you need; it's just a question of assembling them in a way that works.  In particular, you can do this via a well chosen `xsl:sort` key.

You want the CDs with artist Rehman to be output before all the others, so let's start with an XPath expression that expresses that condition when evaluated with a `<cd>` element as the current node:

```
artist = 'Rehman'
```

A sort key can be any XPath expression; its value will be converted to a string (and possibly afterward reinterpreted as a number).  The expression above evaluates to a boolean, and when converted to a string that will result in either `'true'` or `'false'`.  Since `'true'` comes lexicographically after `'false'`, and you want the CDs for which the expression is true to be output first, you'll want to specify descending order for that key:

```
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <xsl:sort select="artist = 'Rehman'" order="descending"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

If you wanted to further refine the order, e.g. to present the remaining records in alphabetical order by artist, then you could add any number of additional sort keys; multiple keys applying to the same scope are ascribed significance from greatest to least according to the order in which they appear.